# linux script running c program

Tags: c, linux, bash

i tried to run a script in linux to run a c program
the script was as follows

```
#!/bin/bash
`gcc odd.c -o odd222`
`chmod +x odd222`
echo `./odd222`
```

and odd.c is

```
main()
{
int i;
printf("enter the no.");
scanf("%d",&i);
printf("shiv");
}
```

but the problem is that when i run this script the all the scanf statement are executed then all the outputs are shown simentaniously....

if i do not put echo before `./odd222` then it says error enter command not found("enter" the first element in printf.

kindly help me

Comment: What you're asking is very unclear. It's also unclear why you are using grave accents in your script... remove them all and replace the last line with a simple "./odd222" (without the quotes) and I think things will work as you expect.

Comment: There are a few glitches in your script. First of all you should not have to make odd222 file executable. gcc should handle that by itself. Second don't echo your odd222's output. Try ./odd222 directly in your script.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Get rid of the backticks, the chmod, and the `echo`. All you need to do is run `gcc`, then run your program.

```
#!/bin/bash
gcc odd.c -o odd222
./odd222
```

It'd also be good to only try to run the program if it compiles successfully. You can make it conditional by using `&&`.

```
#!/bin/bash
gcc odd.c -o odd222 && ./odd222
```

It'd also be good to modify your C code to ensure the printouts are printed immediately. Output is usually line buffered, meaning it's only displayed once you write a full line with a newline `\n` at the end. You'll want to either print a newline:

```
printf("enter the no.\n");
```

Or flush the output explicitly:

```
printf("enter the no.");
fflush(stdout);
```

Answer (score 2):

For running a C language program using a gcc shell script, see the following:

It is also applicable to any language. Modify according to language and
compiler.

**Step 1:**

Create any file having .sh extension (shell script)

For example: *your_file_name.sh*

**Step 2:**

**Contents of file as follows:**

```
gcc `pwd`/"$filename.c"

./"a.out"
```

**Step 3:**

Change permission for read, write, and execute file in terminal using the following command:

```
sudo chmod 777 filename.c
```

**Step 4:**

Execute file on terminal.

You must run the program from the directory where your source file is present because I have used the present working directory (if you want to select any spec).

```
./your_file_name.sh     filename.c
```

**Example Screenshot:**

[image: Example Screenshot]

Comment: Kotlin Compiler Script                                                                                                                kotlinc `pwd`/"$1.kt" -include-runtime -d "$1.jar"
java -jar "$1.jar"

Comment: why not `cc` instead? `cc` isn't portable, but it's an alias of either GCC or Clang.

Answer (score 1):

You need not do to

```
echo `./odd222`
```

If you just write

```
./odd222
```

The shell tries to execute the program according to how it determines the file needs to be executed.Just make these changes,your code will work.

Putting `echo` returns a blank line on the display screen followed by the command prompt on the subsequent line. This is because pressing the ENTER key is a signal to the system to start a new line, and thus echo repeats this signal.

When you write

```
echo `./odd222`
```

it does not recognize the command.Hence it waits there only.echo has nothing to do with our program.

Comment: Your last paragraph is wrong. The `echo` has nothing to do with the input the program receives.

Comment: see my revised answer.I didn't mean that

Comment: I'm afraid the sentences you added are even more confused. The first half of your answer is okay.

Answer (score 0):

**Here are few improvements:**

Remove inverted quotes in your script, No need of them.

These are used when you want to store the return value of command in a variable.

**Example:**

```
var=`gcc odd.c -o odd222`
echo $var # this prints the gcc command output
```

Also run your executable without echo

```
gcc odd.c -o odd222
chmod +x odd222
./odd222
```

You can remove `chmod` line from your script as you have already changed the file to executable mode and there is no need of it everytime.

**odd.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
  int i;
  printf("enter the no.");
  scanf("%d",&i);
  printf("shiv = %d", i);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: @JohnKugelman, thanks edited that, hope it sounds better and clearer now.